# React native fetch api call is not making the request

Tags: react-native, api

I am using an api call to get information for my app which I display to the user. The problem is that when I open the screen for the first time the app displays the information but when I go to a different screen and then comeback I dont see the information unless I restart the app.

This function makes the apiCall for me:

```
async function getOrders() {
    var retrieveData = async () => {
      try {
        var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
        var data = JSON.parse(value);
        return data.user.email;
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    };
    retrieveData().then((usr) => {
      setUser(usr)
      fetch(URL + "/api/order/quoted", {
        method: "POST",
        body: "user=" + usr,
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          if (responseJson.error === null) {
            setOrders(responseJson.orders);
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

First I use the retriveData function to get the used id, based on that information is server to the user.

Comment: What kind of navigation library you use and what is the version?

Comment: I am using react navigation...version 5

Comment: You should store response in redux so it will persist. How are you showing data in view? Please show the complete code so it would easy to guide you accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using react-navigation version 5, so you need to wrap your logic fetch data in useFocusEffect hook [react navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook)

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
     getOrders()
  }, [getOrders])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in the following steps:

- If you want the data fetched from your endpoint to be used even if you move to other screen use Redux.
- If you use redux or not and want to fetch the api every time you open a specific screen then you need to add an onfocus listener. An example is here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });
  }
```